# How to use re.findall to get the url string?

Tags: python, regular-language

```
"foldGroup.registerImage({ domId: 'listimg7', srcUrl: 'https://ec.yimg.com/ec/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fd3vv6xw699rjh3.cloudfront.net%2F9f689b-1904037587_1_160.jpg&t=1460964135&ttl=43200&maxWidth=160&maxHeight=160&sig=QSY1BP0sCebMxqEN6irjXQ--~C' });"
```

This is a part of the html from a yahoo shopping page, like:
 https://shopping.yahoo.com/womens-intimate-apparel/?b=3937

My question is how to find all the img urls using the Python's `re.findall()`?

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't use a real parser?

Comment: because there javascrip code in html,the page crawled can be parsed fully

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
re.findall(r"'https://.*?'", part_of_html)
```

> **[re.findall(pattern, string, flags=0)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall)** Return all non-overlapping matches of pattern in string, as a list of strings. The string is scanned left-to-right, and matches are returned in the order found. If one or more groups are present in the pattern, return a list of groups; this will be a list of tuples if the pattern has more than one group. Empty matches are included in the result unless they touch the beginning of another match.

Comment: thank you, that is really helpful